# Java Tone Recognition

Tags: java, audio, communication

I am looking to do a project where I would need to listen (using system line (mic) input) to an audio stream comprised of 16 distinct tones, and to classify them.  I don't need the code to determine the frequency, just a predefined hex value (ex a 500MHz frequency could translate to a '4' in hex, determined by me).

Does Java (must be desktop, not Android) have the facilities to determine tones like this?

In simpler terms, the input source could sound like morse code but with 16 pitched tones instead of 2 timed-tones.

Comment: No I don't believe that core Java by itself can do something like this, nor can most all other general purpose programming languages, but there are likely utilities or libraries that can do this sort of thing, or at least Fourier analysis of sounds, and perhaps you will want to Google for this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm. I'm sure there are java implementations.